# Having issues trying to print out data read from file into a structure

Tags: c, file, structure

I am attempting to write a program in C that will read a text file with data about different employees and then print this data out. I am unsure at this point if it is an issue with the read file function or the print function. The code is running with no errors, but will only print out that the file has been opened successfully. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct personTag
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
};

struct officialTag
{
    int deptId;
    char cmpName[20];
    double salary;
};

struct employeeTag
{
    struct personTag personalInfo;
    struct officialTag officialInfo;
    struct employeeTag *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct employeeTag EmployeeTag;
typedef EmployeeTag *EmployeeTagPtr;

void readFile()
{
   
   char str[80];

    FILE *filePointer=fopen("employee.txt","r");
    if(filePointer==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in opening of employee.txt file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        printf("File opened successfully!\n");
    fgets(str,100,filePointer);
    while(!feof(filePointer))
    {
        EmployeeTagPtr startPtr=NULL;
        EmployeeTagPtr newPtr, tempPtr;
        newPtr=(EmployeeTag*)malloc(sizeof(EmployeeTag));
        newPtr -> nextPtr = NULL;
        fscanf(filePointer,"%s",newPtr->personalInfo.name);
        fscanf(filePointer,"%d",&newPtr->personalInfo.age);
        fscanf(filePointer,"%d",&newPtr->officialInfo.deptId);
        fscanf(filePointer,"%s",newPtr->officialInfo.cmpName);
        fscanf(filePointer,"%lf",&newPtr->officialInfo.salary);
        if(startPtr==NULL)
        startPtr=newPtr;
        else
        {
            tempPtr=newPtr;
            while(tempPtr -> nextPtr!=NULL)
            tempPtr=tempPtr -> nextPtr;
            tempPtr -> nextPtr= newPtr;
        }
    }
    fclose(filePointer);
    }
}

void printList(EmployeeTagPtr currentPtr){
    while(currentPtr != NULL){
        printf("Name: %s\t Age: %d\t Department ID: %d\t Company: %s\t Salary%lf\n", currentPtr->personalInfo.name, currentPtr->personalInfo.age, currentPtr->officialInfo.deptId, currentPtr->officialInfo.cmpName, currentPtr->officialInfo.salary);
        currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
}


int main()
{
    EmployeeTagPtr startPtr=NULL;

    printf("Welcome to the Employee Database\n");
    
    readFile();

    printList(startPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare `startPtr` in two different places?

Comment: The `startPtr` that you're passing to `printList()` is a local variable in `main()`. `readFile()` updated its own local variable.

Comment: And since you declare `startPtr` inside the `while` loop, it gets recreated each time through the loop. So you're not creating a linked list.

Comment: `readFile()` needs to create `startPtr` before the loop. Then it needs to return it so you can assign this to the variable in `main()`.

Comment: @Barmar Hi thanks so much for reaching out to help, I am in my first year of uni so I am still pretty terrible at this. So if I declare the startptr at the beginning of function, and then when you say return it, will i need to change function from void to something else?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change `void` to `EmployeeTag*`.

Answer (score 0):

I copied in your code and experimented with a few things to knock some of the kinks out.  Following is a version of your code with some revisions in order to retrieve data from a text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct personTag
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
};

struct officialTag
{
    int deptId;
    char cmpName[20];
    double salary;
};

struct employeeTag
{
    struct personTag personalInfo;
    struct officialTag officialInfo;
    struct employeeTag *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct employeeTag EmployeeTag;
typedef EmployeeTag *EmployeeTagPtr;

EmployeeTagPtr readFile()
{
    char str[100];
    EmployeeTagPtr startPtr=NULL;
    EmployeeTagPtr newPtr, tempPtr;
    newPtr=(EmployeeTag*)malloc(sizeof(EmployeeTag));
    newPtr -> nextPtr = NULL;

    char    x_name[20];
    int     x_age = 0;
    int     x_deptId = 0;
    char    x_cmpName[20];
    double  x_salary = 0.00;
    int     ff = 0;

    FILE *filePointer=fopen("employee.txt","r");
    if(filePointer==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in opening of employee.txt file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File opened successfully!\n");
        fgets(str,100,filePointer);
        while(!feof(filePointer))
        {
            ff = sscanf(str,"%20[^\t] %d %d %s %lf", x_name, &x_age, &x_deptId, x_cmpName, &x_salary); /* Use sscanf instead of fscanf */
            if (ff <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            if(startPtr == NULL)
            {
                startPtr = newPtr;
            }
            else
            {
                tempPtr = newPtr;
                newPtr=(EmployeeTag*)malloc(sizeof(EmployeeTag));
                newPtr -> nextPtr = NULL;
                tempPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            }

            strcpy(newPtr->personalInfo.name, x_name);
            newPtr->personalInfo.age = x_age;
            newPtr->officialInfo.deptId = x_deptId;
            strcpy(newPtr->officialInfo.cmpName, x_cmpName);
            newPtr->officialInfo.salary = x_salary;
            fgets(str,100,filePointer);
        }
        fclose(filePointer);
    }
    return startPtr;
}

void printList(EmployeeTagPtr currentPtr)
{
    while(currentPtr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\t Age: %d\t Department ID: %d\t Company: %s\t Salary: %lf\n", currentPtr->personalInfo.name, currentPtr->personalInfo.age, currentPtr->officialInfo.deptId, currentPtr->officialInfo.cmpName, currentPtr->officialInfo.salary);
        currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
}


int main()
{
    printf("Welcome to the Employee Database\n");

    EmployeeTagPtr startPtr = readFile();

    printList(startPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

The key things to point out are:

- The repositioning of the "startPtr" and "nextPtr" updating in the "readFile" function.
- The revision of the signature for the "readFile" function so that it returns the pointer for the first employee structure to be used by your "printList" function.
- The rework of your "scanf" statements using "sscanf" such that there is only one "sscanf" process occurring for each file record read rather than attempting to retrieve each data element individually.
- Also, the need to allocate memory (malloc) for each record being read.

If you scan through this version of your code there probably are some other minor tweaks I made, but those were the key changes in order to read and list your data.  As a test, I populated a sample text file and the ran the program to see if it would produce output.  Following is a sample of the output on my terminal.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Employees/bin/Release$ ./Employees 
Welcome to the Employee Database
File opened successfully!
Name: Joseph Jones   Age: 44     Department ID: 144  Company: Acme   Salary: 2000.000000
Name: Bill Smith     Age: 35     Department ID: 222  Company: Acme   Salary: 1800.000000
```

This should allow you to progress on your coding.  Please experiment with these changes.